# python and kivy input text in first windows after click button print ( text ) as label ( update label ) in second widows

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I want create simple app and I'm new in python, this app contain two windows , at first windows have one button (Save) and two input text.
at the second windows we have four label.
after click on button in first windows the label ( username 1 print here ) in second windows change according text input in first windows.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbqGG.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCFMq.png)

when I run my code the label not change, any one can help me what is wrong.

python code

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen,ScreenManager
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class Main_windows(Screen):
    f_user = ObjectProperty(None)
    player = ObjectProperty(None)

    def btn_save(self):
       self.player=self.f_user.text
class Second_windows(Screen):
    pass
class Windows_manager(ScreenManager):
    pass
kv=Builder.load_file("vop.kv")

class Vop(App):
    def build(self):
    return kv
```

kivy code :

```
## Collect our windows to windows manager ##
Windows_manager:
  Main_windows:
  Second_windows:


<Main_windows>:
  f_user:f_user



  name:"main_windows"
  BoxLayout:
    orientation:"vertical"
    Label:
        text: "Please insert Name of First Player"

    TextInput:
        id: f_user
        multiline:False
    Label:
        text: "please insert Name of Second Player"
    TextInput:
        id: s_user
        multiline:False

    Button:
        text:"Save"
        on_release:

            app.root.current="second_windows"
            root.manager.transition.direction="up"
            root.btn_save()


<Second_Windows>:

  player:player


  name:"second_windows"
  BoxLayout:
    orientation :"vertical"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"horizontal"

        Label:
            id:player
            text:"User number one"
        Label:
            id:player2
            text:"User number Two"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"horizontal"
        Label:
            text: "user name 1 print here"
        Label:
            text: "user name 2 print here"
    Button:
        text:"Back"
        on_release:
            app.root.current="main_windows"
            root.manager.transition.direction="down"
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code, the main objective is getting data from one class to the other. This method works only when we are dealing with `Screen` and `ScreenManager`. I'm also trying to figure out how we can transfer data between classes. If I figured out the other method, I will update my answer.

*python code*:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen,ScreenManager
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class Main_windows(Screen):
    f_user = ObjectProperty(None)
       
class Second_windows(Screen):
    player1 = ObjectProperty(None)

class Windows_manager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Vop(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("vop.kv")
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Vop().run()
```

*kivy code*:

```
## Collect our windows to windows manager ##

#: kivy 2.0.0

Windows_manager:
    Main_windows:
    Second_windows:

<Main_windows>:
    f_user:f_user

    name:"main_windows"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"vertical"
        Label:
            text: "Please insert Name of First Player"

        TextInput:
            id: f_user
            multiline:False
        Label:
            text: "please insert Name of Second Player"
        TextInput:
            id: s_user
            multiline:False

        Button:
            text:"Save"
            on_release:
                app.root.current="second_windows"
                root.manager.transition.direction="up"
                root.manager.get_screen('second_windows').player1.text = root.f_user.text

<Second_Windows>:

    name:"second_windows"

    player1: player1

    BoxLayout:
        orientation :"vertical"

        BoxLayout:
            orientation:"horizontal"

            Label:
                text:"User number one"
            Label:
                text:"User number Two"

        BoxLayout:
            orientation:"horizontal"
            Label:
                id: player1
                text: '' # change here
            Label:
                id: player2
                text: "user name 2 print here"
        Button:
            text:"Back"
            on_release:
                app.root.current="main_windows"
                root.manager.transition.direction="down"
```

***App Screenshots***

[image: Main_Window]

[image: Second_Window]